# How to use Branch.io to create a referral program for iOS app?

Tags: ios, branch.io

I have not been able to find a complete guide to creating a useful referral program in the Branch.io documentation. At the moment, I have the iOS SDK integrated as well as the dashboard setup correctly. I am using `BranchUniversalObject` and `BranchLinkProperties` and then showing the share sheet when a user attempts to share their referral yet when I click on the shared link, there is no reference to the user who referred the new user. I am setting a custom parameter `referringUserID` but that doesn't seem to get passed into the deep link when the user launches the app after download. I am also setting the `canonicalIdentifier` for the `BranchUniversalObject`. Is it better to generate a unique URL upon user account creation then use that from the share sheet and compare the `+non_branch_link` upon user launch? The code below is what I have for the current implementation of how we display the share sheet. What is the proper way to share links on iOS to track actual referrals?

```
let branchUniversalObject = BranchUniversalObject(canonicalIdentifier: Session.shared.userId!)
branchUniversalObject.title = "My Share Link"
branchUniversalObject.contentDescription = "Share"

        // Feature (utm_medium) = marketing, referrals
        // Channel (utm_source) = sticker, referral link, etc
        // Campaign (itm_campaign) = launch, holiday season, etc.
        // Tags = June Offer, Summer, Launch Promo
        let branchLinkProperties = BranchLinkProperties()
        branchLinkProperties.campaign = "Referral"
        //branchLinkProperties.channel = "Referral Link"
        branchLinkProperties.feature = "referrals"
        branchLinkProperties.addControlParam("referringUserID", withValue: Session.shared.userId!)

        branchUniversalObject.showShareSheet(
            with: branchLinkProperties,
            andShareText: "",
            from: viewController,
            completion: nil)
```

Comment: Can you also add a sample link and the params you are actually getting from the Branch SDK when you are reading that link? Ideally the SDK response should contain `referringUserID` which you make use of here

Comment: It does seem that the proper information is coming with the shared link. I attempted to click on a link with the app already installed and saw all of the relevant information. The same information will come if a user clicks the link, downloads the app, then launches the app too, right?

Comment: That's correct both deferred and regular deep linking should work